# List won't display items in LocalStorage on launch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, local-storage

Using Sencha Touch 2.4.1, I have a List that displays currencies, a FormPanel where the user can add new currencies. The store is "prepopulated" with two items, and they are displayed correctly in the List. When the user adds new items they are also displayed correctly in the List.

But when the app is restarted, I'm back to square one again - only the "prepopulated" items are displayed in the List - any items that were added on the last app execution have disappeared. Although I can see them all in the Local Storage in Google Chrome's Developer Tools... why aren't they displayed in my List?

STORE

```
Ext.define('DebtManager.store.Currency', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires : [
        'DebtManager.model.Currency',
        'Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage'
    ],

    config : {
        autoLoad: true,
        model: 'DebtManager.model.Currency',
        storeId: 'CurrencyStore',

        sorters: [{
            property: 'title',
            direction: 'ASC'
        }],

        proxy: {            
            type: 'localstorage',
            model: 'DebtManager.model.Currency',
            id: 'currenciesLocalstore', // The name of the LocalStorage

            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'currencies'
            }            
        },


        data: [
            {
                id: 1,   
                title: 'USD',
                dollarExchangeRate: '1.0'
            },
            {
                id: 2,   
                title: 'SEK',
                dollarExchangeRate: '8.4'
            }
        ]        
    },


    load : function (store, records, success, opr) {
        console.log('Store loaded.');   
    },

    beforeSync : function (options, eOpts) {
        console.log('Syncing store...');   
    },

    addrecords : function( store, records, eOpts ){
        console.log('Record(s) added to store');
    }

});
```

LIST PANEL

```
Ext.define('DebtManager.view.CurrenciesListPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype: 'panel',

    requires: [
        'DebtManager.store.Currency',       
    ],

    config: {
        title: 'Currencies',
        iconCls: 'action',  

        layout: 'fit',

        items: [
            {
                docked: 'top',      
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                title: 'Currencies tab',
                items: [
                    { xtype: 'spacer' },
                    {
                        id: 'newNoteButton',
                        text: 'Add',
                        ui: 'action',

                        handler: function () {                          
                            console.log('Add currency');
                            var editorPanel = Ext.create('DebtManager.view.CurrencyEditorPanel');
                            var currency = Ext.create( 'DebtManager.model.Currency', {title: 'xxx', dollarExchangeRate: '100'} );                           
                            editorPanel.setRecord( currency );                          
                            Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem( editorPanel, {type: 'slide', direction: 'left'});                           
                        }
                    }
                ]               
            },
            Ext.create('Ext.List', {
                id: 'currenciesListPanelList',
                title: 'Currencies list',
                store: Ext.create('DebtManager.store.Currency'), 
                itemTpl: '<div class="list-item-title">{title}</div>' + '<div class="list-item-narrative">{dollarExchangeRate}</div>',

                onItemDisclosure: function (record) {
                    // Edit item
                    console.log('Edit item');
                },

                show: function (list, opts) {
                    console.log('List Shown: ' + list);
                }

            })
        ],        

    },

});
```

EDITOR PANEL

```
Ext.define('DebtManager.view.CurrencyEditorPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.FormPanel',

    requires: [
        'DebtManager.store.Currency',
    ],

    config: {        
        fullscreen: true,
        title: 'Edit currency',

        items: [
            {
                docked: 'top',      
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                title: 'Edit currency',
                items: [
                    {
                        id: 'backButton',
                        text: 'Back',
                        ui: 'back',

                        handler: function () {                          
                            Ext.Viewport.remove(Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem(), true); // Remove this panel                           
                        }
                    },
                    { xtype: 'spacer' },
                    {
                        id: 'saveButton',
                        text: 'Save',
                        ui: 'action',

                        handler: function () {                          
                            console.log('Save');

                            var editor = Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem(); 
                            var currentCurrency = editor.getRecord();
                            editor.updateRecord( currentCurrency );



                            var store = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('CurrencyStore');

                            if (store.findRecord('id', currentCurrency.getData().id) === null) {
                                console.log('Adding record to store...');
                                console.log( currentCurrency );
                                store.add(currentCurrency);
                            } else {
                                console.log('Marking record as dirty...');
                                currentCurrency.setDirty();
                            }

                            store.sync();


                            Ext.getCmp('currenciesListPanelList').refresh();

                            Ext.Viewport.remove(Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem(), true); // Remove this panel                           

                        }
                    }
                ]               
            },
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'id',
                label: 'ID',
                required: true
            },            
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'title',
                label: 'Title',
                required: true
            },            
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'dollarExchangeRate',
                label: 'USD Exchange Rate',
                required: true
            },
            {
                docked: 'bottom',      
                xtype: 'toolbar',                
                items: [
                    { xtype: 'spacer' },
                    {
                        id: 'deleteButton',
                        iconCls: 'trash',
                        iconMask: true,

                        handler: function () {                          
                            console.log('Delete');
                        }
                    }
                ]               
            },

        ]
    }
});
```

MODEL

```
Ext.define('DebtManager.model.Currency', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    requires: [
    ],

    config: {
        idProperty: 'id',        
        identifier: { 
            type: 'uuid',
            isUnique : true 
        }, 

        fields: [
            {
                name: 'title',
                type: 'string'
            },
            {
                name: 'dollarExchangeRate',
                type: 'string'
            }
        ],
    }
});
```

LocalStorage in Google Chrome

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change few configuration in Store and List.

***Changes in Store***

1. Load,beforeSync and addrecords are listeners So, place it inside listeners
2. Listeners should be inside config
3. Don't need to repeat `model: 'DebtManager.model.Currency'` inside
   proxy

***Updated Store***

```
Ext.define('DebtManager.store.Currency', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires : [
        'DebtManager.model.Currency',
        'Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage'
    ],

    config : {
        autoLoad: true,
        model: 'DebtManager.model.Currency',
        storeId: 'CurrencyStore',

        sorters: [{
            property: 'title',
            direction: 'ASC'
        }],

        proxy: {            
            type: 'localstorage',
            id: 'currenciesLocalstore', // The name of the LocalStorage
        },


        listeners : {
            load : function (store, records, success, opr) {
                console.log('Store loaded.');   
            },

            beforeSync : function (options, eOpts) {
                console.log('Syncing store...');   
            },

            addrecords : function( store, records, eOpts ){
                console.log('Record(s) added to store');
            }        
        }
    }
});
```

***Changes in List***

1. You defined list using `Ext.create`, Not sure about this. I changed
   it
2. onItemDisclosure,show are listeners So, place it inside listeners
3. Use storeId for connecting list with store like `store: 'CurrencyStore'` instead of `store: Ext.create('DebtManager.store.Currency')`
4. Don't use predefined `xtype` for your custom views so, i changed
   `xtype: 'panel'` to `xtype: 'currencyListPanel'`

***Updated TabPanel***

```
Ext.define('DebtManager.view.CurrenciesListPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype: 'currencyListPanel',

    requires: [
        'DebtManager.store.Currency',       
    ],

    config: {
        title: 'Currencies',
        iconCls: 'action',  

        layout: 'fit',

        items: [
            {
                docked: 'top',      
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                title: 'Currencies tab',
                items: [
                    { xtype: 'spacer' },
                    {
                        id: 'newNoteButton',
                        text: 'Add',
                        ui: 'action',

                        handler: function () {                          
                            console.log('Add currency');
                            var editorPanel = Ext.create('DebtManager.view.CurrencyEditorPanel');
                            var currency = Ext.create( 'DebtManager.model.Currency', {title: 'xxx', dollarExchangeRate: '100'} );                           
                            editorPanel.setRecord( currency );                          
                            Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem( editorPanel, {type: 'slide', direction: 'left'});                           
                        }
                    }
                ]               
            },
            {
                xtype : 'list',
                id: 'currenciesListPanelList',
                title: 'Currencies list',
                onItemDisclosure: true,
                store: 'CurrencyStore', 
                itemTpl: '<div class="list-item-title">{title}</div>' + '<div class="list-item-narrative">{dollarExchangeRate}</div>',
                listeners : {
                    onItemDisclosure: function (record) {
                        // Edit item
                        console.log('Edit item');
                    },

                    show: function (list, opts) {
                        console.log('List Shown: ' + list);
                    }                    
                }

            }
        ],        

    },

});
```

***Additional Note***

Use `itemId` with `getComponent()` instead of `id` with `getCmp()`.

To know more [See This Screencast](https://vimeo.com/14816550)

Finally, Here is the complete code in [Sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/mf6)

Comment: Thanks! The code I posted actually comes from a couple of tutorials combined with snippets from the official Sencha docs. I have just started playing around with Sencha, and my first impression is that there are a lot of deprecated, conflicting and just plain wrong examples and tutorials... I even found some conflicting examples in the Sencha docs... any advice on good tutorials and examples? I'm just playing for now, so investing in a book at this moment is not something I'm willing to do.

Comment: Sencha Touch Docs is only thing you need. There are lot of blogs and 4 such blogs will implement same task in 4 different way, but sencha wil keep on updating there lib. So it's always better to be upto date with docs.